# Character encoding and SSH

Tags: ssh, putty

I've configured 2 ssh servers on the same Win 7 machine. The first one is `Freesshd` (running on port 22) and the second is `openSSH` (running on port 25). I'm connecting remotely to both servers using putty with translation option set `UTF-8`. When connecting to `openSSH` the encoding seems to be ok - all my polish chars is displayed correctly. When i connect to `Freesshd` i got weird chars. Does that mean that both servers using different encodings and if how to check it's encodings an how to set it on both servers?

Comment: a)check the font supports the unicode characters that you want b)have you tried the command `chcp 65001`?   (though I doubt chcp will make any difference..) but can you elaborate on weird characters.. like do you mean commands display weird characters, or do you mean when you type then weird ones appear. It might help to see what weird ones appear perhaps it might hint to the issue.

Comment: it may be worth trying openssh client without putty e.g. cygwin's implementation of openssh, but perhaps try it from a cmd.exe and connect to freesshd server..  See if the cmd.exe you are starting from displays the characters correctly and then after that see if  you still have the ability once connected remotely..